# Trouble installing SciPy on windows 7

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, scipy

I am newbie in Python. Before I tried to install this library, I installed NumPy. I don't know why this error occurred error when installing SciPy. Here is the image of the error:

[image]

Please give me a step by step description of the installation process of SciPy.

Comment: Most important bit is that you start the command window with admin rightsd

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to install SciPy on Windows is using [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads). This gives you a lot of popular scientific Python packages. All work together. It takes about 2GB on your hard drive because it installs many packages, many of which you won't use, but saves you a lot of time.

Alternatively, you can use [Miniconda](http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html). This uses less space. It gives you a basic Python install with `conda`. Then you can install packages individually with:

```
conda install scipy
```

Comment: Anaconda/Miniconda is a blessing!

Comment: Works like charm .... thanks mate @MikeMüller but mate how to install pylab in anaconda in win 7 64bit..thanks anyway

Comment: pylab is a part of matplotlib. It is included in Anaconda. With Miniconda: `conda install matplotlib`. Then: `from matplotlib import pylab`.

Answer (score 2):

Lets start from the beginning. Try installing SciPy with pip via the Windows command line. The command is:

```
pip install scipy
```

You will need to make sure you have Python set in your system path. Take a look at this tutorial if you are confused about that:
http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

If the installation with pip doesn't work (which it never has for me with SciPy) then you can install it via whl file which you can grab from the University of California Irvine. Grab the file for your system architecture here:
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Then, in the command prompt, go to the directory where you downloaded the appropriate whl file and enter the following command:

```
pip install name_of_whl_file.whl
```

You should be good to go after that.